# Fix scratch on quartz countertop

Tags: bathroom, countertops, quartz

My quartz countertop has a faint scratch on it. Is there a way to repair or at least obfuscate it? [image]

[image]

Comment: Polish, polish polish

Comment: what caused the scratch?  the slabs come with factory polish so it can be hard to get it to look exactly the same.  you might be able to polish it with 8000 grit diamond pads but I'd get a test piece of quartz, re-create the scratch and then test with the various grits or consult with a solid surface installer and see what they recommend.

Comment: That's not a scratch. It's a scuff or abrasion.

Comment: a lot of times scuffs can be made to virtually disappear. I would try clear nail polish applied over the whole area. squeegee off when still wet and let dry. Buff gently and not-so-gently with wet and dry rags until the polish on the non-scuff parts is removed. If it looks worse you can just remove it all, no damage and little wasted cost. A way to "preview" the results is to see if the spot looks better when wet with plain water; if so, the polish trick is promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave it be, you'll probably make it worse and more noticeable than it is. Besides, I see no scratches except for a scuff.

If you're not prepared to re-polish all visible surfaces then whatever you do will just attract even more attention.

As for how to perform the repair I would start with some YouTube videos and gauge which method you would feel comfortable carrying out. I have zero clue what your skill nor willingness level is so I have no specific recommendation for technique.